# Finding The Median

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I am a first year student. I have had some exposure to statistics, but I do not know very much. Is there is a statistical method to find the median of marks given only the average of the marks and the number of students in the class?

Comment: You can learn a great deal, quickly, about the relationships between median and mean by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=median+mean+).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the answer is no. The median cannot be determined given only the average (assuming you refer to the mean) and sample size. For a counterexample, consider the following set of three test scores.
$$75, 86, 94$$
The mean of this set is $(75+86+94)/3 = 85$ and the median is $86$. Now consider the set
$$74, 87, 94.$$
These three numbers have the same mean as before, but the median becomes $87$.

---

As @Alexis suggests in the comments, it is worth considering a third set
$$75, 86, 100.$$
Here, the mean increases to $87$ while the median stays at $86$.

Comment: Are there strong assumptions that would allow you to recover it?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov, not that I can think of. At least nothing that stays true to the spirit of the question. If you come up with anything let me know.